# The difference between "to someone" and "for someone"

Tags: differences, prepositions, to-for

> To many people, we are the scariest animals in the world.
>
> For me, English is the easiest of all subjects.

Why does the former sentence use "to" someone and the latter use "for" someone?
What are the differences?

Comment: Good question. Perhaps you should be asking on ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question has been asked before. Follow the link or browse the [dedicated tag](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/to-for).